# Чем отличается шпион от разведчика?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Это одно и то же?

Шпион как будто плохая профессия, а разведчик хорошая? Но кому из них лучше платят, непонятно?

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить упрощённо, то шпион - это *вражеский разведчик (в действии)*, отсюда сильно выраженный негативный оттенок, которого нет напр. у английского слова *spy*. Разведчик - это профессия (в нейтральном смысле), шпион же в русском - *оценочное* понятие: это человек, от которого можно ждать неприятностей.

Comment: Замечательное разъяснение!